# How to avoid C3P0 logging framework from generation lots of String objects

Tags: performance, c3p0

During a performance test with c3p0, I found that com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.trace() is creating a lots of string objects. Although the strings output are suppressed by the slf4j log instance (as the log level is warn), this contributed significantly on the object allocation rate. Do we have any configuration of avoiding this? Thanks in advance.

logback.xml

```
<logger name="com.mchange" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" />
</logger>
```

pom.xml

```
    <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>


    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

So `BasicResourcePool.trace()` is [properly guarded](https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/7091e563f0bded9583f68b72639434c108606691/src/java/com/mchange/v2/resourcepool/BasicResourcePool.java#L1792-L1805) to test the logger for `FINEST` (which should map to `TRACE` before allocating Strings. The question then is why, given your config, are the Strings being allocated?

The answer turns out to be... I screwed up. The guard methods in the bridge library to slf4j logging improperly reported that loggers were logging at levels that they were not (in the `mchange-commons-java` library on which `c3p0` depends). Pretty bad. I'll try to publish a fix tonight (and notify you with a comment).

Comment: OK. c3p0-0.9.5.2 is out, and includes a fix. On maven central / sourceforge / github.